# How query Db with datetimeoff using entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I want to query the database with a column with datetimeoffset(7). This takes startDate and endDate as seen in the code below.

my URL is something like this

`http://localhost:60018/v1/getDepartPoints?startDate=2015-08-08&endDate=2015-08-08`

Below is my query that returned 0 list

`var result = Db.Points.Where(t => t.DepartureTime > startDate && t.DepartureTime < endDate).ToList();`

Below is the sql query that works
 `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Points] WHERE DepartureTime = '2015-08-08 04:35:00.0000000 -10:00'`

This below query didnt work as I expected after casting to datetime
  `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Points] WHERE cast(DepartureTime as datetime) = '2015-08-08'`

How can I make my query return the expected list with the datetime passed to datetimeoffset in the Database?

Comment: I think you mean datetimeoffset, but question does not sense as it stands

Comment: Yes, datetimeoffset, I will update mu question

Comment: `'2015-08-08 04:35:00.0000000 -10:00'` and `'2015-08-08'` are completely different times; why would you expect them to return the same value? The latter would be inferred as `'2015-08-08 00:00:00.0000000 {Server Offset}`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for pointing that out. I am looking for a way to make this work. should I make it compulsory for API users to pass something ```'2015-08-08 00:00:00.0000000 -10:00' or there is a way to manipulate it in the code when they pass ```'2015-08-08'```

Comment: @techstack if the users pass in '2015-08-08' what time is expected?  Is that time midnight UTC?  Midnight local time - midnight server time?  If you are using datetimeoffset - then the client (users) need to send a datetimeoffset so you know what time is being passed into the procedure.